# Connecting to a Shared Data Source at Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am writing a report builder program that is similar to Microsoft's [Report Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207008%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but to be hosted on an existing web application. It should be able to:

- connect to a report server (SSRS2008) and a pre-configured shared data source;
- let the user design RDLCs; and,
- dynamically generate reports without the need for Visual Studio.

Basically, it's a stand-alone albeit proprietary report generation tool.

The users need not be *report writers* but do they have an understanding on how data is correlated in the database. (There are existing relationships between tables.) For some reason, they cannot or should not have access to the SSRS site to build reports from there (i.e. use Microsoft's Report Builder tool). They have to use the tool I am creating.

I'm very much done with the last two bullets. The first one is giving me the issue: I'm relatively new to this and probably it's not trivial. How can I connect to an SSRS2008 data source at runtime?

In my `web.config`, I added an entry to the connectionStrings like so:

```
<add name="ReportingSDS" connectionString="Server=http://myReportingServer;datasource=http://myReportingServer/reportserver/models/myReportModel.smdl;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

which is based on the [prescribed format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

And I ran into a brick wall after this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReportingSDS"].ConnectionString))
{
     conn.Open();
     // what's next?
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My goal is to retrieve that `DataSet` and plug it into this snippet:

```
using (var memRDLC = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myRdlcXml)))
{
    // Bind the rdl memory stream and data set to reportviewer
    rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

    LocalReport r = rptViewer.LocalReport;
    r.LoadReportDefinition(memRDLC);
    foreach (DataTable dataTable in reportEngine.DataTables)
    {
        r.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(
            dataTable.TableName + "_Table", dataTable));
    }
    r.Refresh();
}
```